# PHP Insert into my database won't work

Tags: php

I'm trying to insert html input into my database. Php returns me no error, but when I go to my database, there is nothing, why ?

```
if(isset($_POST['texte'])) {
        $texte = $_POST['texte'];
        try 
        {
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=textes', 'root', '');
            $req = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO textes VALUES(txt)');
            $req->execute(array(
                'txt' => $texte
            ));

            echo 'Le jeu a bien été ajouté !';
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
                die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Read [this](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: be aware that PDO isn't in "Exception mode" by default, rather will simply set the error code for you to inspect, unless you change this behavior with `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Have you looked in your php error log recently?

Comment: Be advised PDO throws a `PDOException` object and not an `Exception` object

Comment: @RiggsFolly PDOExeption inherits from Exception, so it should catch it regardless

Comment: @silkfire Yup almost true, but as almost everything else with this code is wrong and it is better to catch the real exception object. Also PDOException extends `RuntimeException` and adds at least 2 properties i.e. `errorInfo` and `code`

Comment: POST array probably failing at this point.

Answer (score 1):

PDO named parameters start with a `:`:

```
        $req = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO textes VALUES(:txt)');
        $req->execute(array(
            ':txt' => $texte
        ));
```

Comment: I added it but nothing.....

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the database, you probably required transactionality - this means commit; or rollback;.  You should check to verify that autocommit is on.  Otherwise, your insert will succeed but the data may not be saved.

Answer (score -1):

```
  $req = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO textes VALUES(:txt)");
  $req->execute(array(
                "txt" => $texte
  ));`);
```

let me know if works.